# Continue printed text to next line in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label

I have a line of text that I want to make look better by cutting off the end and printing it to the next line. I am using Tkinter and trying to make a Label use 3 lines instead of 1 as the text is WAY too long to display.

```
label4Text.set("0.0.0.0 This subnet mask is non-routable as there is no network portion")
```

It looks like this:

```
[0.0.0.0 This subnet mask is non-routable as there is no network portion]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
[0.0.0.0

This subnet mask is non-routable

There is no network portion]
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried adding line break characters?  (`\n`)

Comment: Yeah. I can't seem to get it to work...

Comment: Multi-line labels work out of the box for me: http://pastebin.com/E2CRrYrb. Please provide a [short, self-contained, runnable sample](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits your problem.

Comment: @KraigClubb please also include what errors you encountered in using the line break character (`\n`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\n`, like:

```
label4Text.set("0.0.0.0\nThis subnet mask is non-routable\nas there is no network portion")
```

Demo:

```
In [4]: s = "0.0.0.0 \nThis subnet mask is non-routable\nThere is no network portion"

In [5]: print s
0.0.0.0 
This subnet mask is non-routable
There is no network portion
```

Comment: It's not working. It is only showing "This subnet mask is non-routable" Is there something I have to do to the label?

Comment: What is `label4Text`?

Comment: Nevermind It did work. I had to change the height of the label from 1 to 3. Thanks a lot!

Comment: label4Text is just a variable set to a label in Tkinter for the GUI